# Внести изменения в скрипт слайдера

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго времени суток, добрые люди! Есть готовый слайдер. Пример работы можете посмотреть [здесь](http://pcvector.net/uploads/demo/scripts/slideshow_and_scroller/flexslider/demo/thumbnail-slider.html#.U0lCBhBJY5s). Меня не устраивает размер миниатюр. Нужно сделать их меньше. Но одних изменений в css файле недостаточно. Прокрутка слайда и карусели миниатюр как-то связана и высчитывается скриптом. Изменяешь размер миниатюры и карусель миниатюр как зря начинает прокручиваться. По [ссылке](http://yadi.sk/d/E8_PkbbQMKJ9f) есть исходники с css-изменениями. Можете посмотреть что получается. 
Меня бы устроило два варианта решения. Готов заплатить.

1. Внести изменения чтобы слайдер работал как в примере по ссылке, но с маленькими миниатюрами. Размер миниатюры должен быть 110px
2. Сделать так чтобы прокрутка карусели миниатюр и слайдов не были связаны. Т.е. если слайды прокручиваешь, карусель миниатюр никак не реагирует. Но при клике на миниатюру слайд должен прокручиваться.

Надеюсь понятно объяснил )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

так там же можно выставить размер миниатюры

```
$('#carousel').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    itemWidth: 210, // тута
    itemMargin: 5,
    asNavFor: '#slider'
  });
```

Comment: Благодарю )) очень помогли